# How to Check Which User Last Logged in to Workstation

Tags: vb.net, powershell, active-directory

I need to create a spreadsheet of which kit is assigned to which person, within the company.

We have desktops & laptops, for the purpose of this post, we'll say desktops are named DESKTOP then a random 3 digit number (DESKTOP001, DESKTOP002 etc.) and laptops are named LAPTOP then a random 3 digit number (LAPTOP001, LAPTOP002 etc.)

I'm presuming the best way of checking which user uses each workstation would be to check who last logged in to it. Could someone provide a way of doing this for ALL computers in a certain OU (lets say DESKTOP_OU for desktops and LAPTOP_OU for laptops in this example) (either with VB Script or PowerShell I would presume) and to export it to Excel.

Alternatively, if there's a better way of checking this, please feel free to suggest.

Comment: the _best_ way to do this is to use an Active Directory server to authenticate the users against and manage everything centrally, which also gives you easy audit logs.

Comment: Perhaps I should've explained in the initial post - this is a Windows domain setup using Windows Server 2008 R2 with Active Directory used for computers, users & permission groups etc. Would you happen to know of an easy way of checking the 'audit logs' to extract who last logged in to each workstation?

Answer (score 1):

Download the PSTools from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897545, then `cd` to the directory you extracted PStools to (it's not a bad idea to put it in your path :-)) in PowerShell:

```
get-adcomputer -filter * -searchbase "ou=whatever" | %{.\psloggedon.exe -l -x ("\\"+$_.DNSHostName)}
```

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for your message. I tried this (downloaded PsTools to a folder on the Desktop) and launched PowerShell. Moved to the directory and ran your code and I received the error: The term 'get-adcomputer' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:15

Any ideas? Appreciate your help with this.

Comment: You need to load the microsoft ad-snapin: **add-pssnapin microsoft.windows.ad**

Comment: If you found this question because you need to know the user last logged on to a particular workstation (as I did), then you just need the psloggedon tool from Scott's post. "psloggedon.exe \\hostname" does the trick. no powershell needed.